# How would I change the HTML structure of a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I have this webpage for testing with content on it.  In 3 other separate HTML files, I have 3 different navigation menus.  What I want to do is include a dropdown menu on the testing page with 3 links in it.  Each link would change the navigation on the testing page.  For example, there is a default navigation on the testing page.  Clicking link 1 in the dropdown would change that navigation.  Same with link 2 and link 3.  How would I do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Use a `.change` function on the drop down, inside that function check the value, then use a `.load()` function to bring in the new nav menu (this is jQuery by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit your requirements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menu1 = $('#navigation-menu1');
  var menu2 = $('#navigation-menu2');
  var menu3 = $('#navigation-menu3');

  $('#link-1').bind('click', function() {
    $('#navigation').empty();
    $('#navigation').append(menu1);
  });
  $('#link-2').bind('click', function() {
    $('#navigation').empty();
    $('#navigation').append(menu2);
  });
  $('#link-3').bind('click', function() {
    $('#navigation').empty();
    $('#navigation').append(menu3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link-1">link 1</a>
<a id="link-2">link 2</a>
<a id="link-3">link 3</a>

<div id="navigation"></div>

<div id="templates" style="display:none;">
  <div id="navigation-menu1">navigation-menu1</div>
  <div id="navigation-menu2">navigation-menu2</div>
  <div id="navigation-menu3">navigation-menu3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way jquery works is that you set up a listener to a certain event with custom code to run whenever that happens.  Here's an example for the link:

```
<a id="mylink" href="home.html">Go Home</a>
```

The javascript(put this in between your  and  tags):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         //This code gets run when the page is finished loading
         $('a#mylink').click(function() {
              //Handle the event here
         });
     });
</script>
```

You also asked how you can change HTML dynamically at run time.  jQuery has a great function for this .html()

Say you have some html:

```
<div id="changeme">Hello</div>
```

The following jQuery:

```
$('#changeme').html("Goodbye");
```

Changes the page's html to the following

```
<div id="changeme">Goodbye</div>
```

Comment: html() is the wrong function in this case. text() returns the pure text contained in the div, whereas html() would return any html tags etc. (if they were present)                                                                                                                 $("#changeme").on("click", function(){
    $("#changeme p").text("Goodbye");
});

Comment: It was a simple example to demonstrate how you can change html.  You can, obviously, change the example to an html string of greater complexity than "Goodbye"

Comment: This was great - I never knew this before, but Matthias was right on the money with what I needed.  I can definitely use this in another part of my page.  Thanks!